# What's the use of ^:dynamic on a defonce?

Tags: clojure, environment-variables

Looking at `clojure.test` [source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/test.clj#L244), I spotted the following:

```
(defonce ^:dynamic
  ^{:doc "True by default.  If set to false, no test functions will
   be created by deftest, set-test, or with-test.  Use this to omit
   tests when compiling or loading production code."
    :added "1.1"}
  *load-tests* true)
```

Is there any benefit or reason behind preventing redefinition (i.e. using `defonce`) of a var which is marked as `^:dynamic`?

Comment: Could it be to prevent a warning from the compiler about having a non-dynamic var named `*something*` ?

Comment: Then the question would be why to use earmuffs on the name, which is expressing the exact same meaning of `^:dynamic` in older versions of Clojure. I'll check if previous versions of `clojure.test` are using different `def` strategies for that var.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`defonce` doesn't prevent redefinition in general, but only when one reloads the file. This is useful typically when the var is maintaining some sort of state or context. I believe the usage of `defonce` here, could be an artifact from development of the library, where the developer needs to reload the file many times during development while still wanting to retain the same value.

Since the var is not pointing to a ref, but a direct var, using `^:dynamic` is the right choice. Now the code can use `set!` or `binding` to change the value in a thread-local way.